# Show Helm candidates at left, immediately above minibuffer

Tags: helm, minibuffer, window-splitting

If I split a frame vertically, keep point in left split and press `M-x`, minibuffer will be on bottom and `M-x` will be in left corner like this.

[image]

This is very convinient as I can 'see' what I am typing and helm sources without moving my head.

On the other hand, If I keep point in right split, press `M-x`, minibuffer will be on bottom and `M-x` still will be in left corner like this.

[image]

If `M-x` starts from the middle, it would be very convenient.

How can I position text in minibuffer w.r.t to split?

Also, when window is split horizontally, how can I position minibuffer at the bottom of top slit?

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do any of this. Check out 1-on-1 frames for a frame-oriented solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to achieve might be tricky (if not impossible) to achieve. But it seems that all you want is to keep the `helm-sources` (the `helm` window) and the minibuffer in same direction so that you can view them without have move your eyes around much. I think this can be achieved using on of the methods below

**1)** Customize `helm` so that the "helm window" is always in the bottom-left window.

Since the minibuffer is always positioned at bottom-left of the screen, this would mean that you can view helm-sources and the minibuffer at once.

We can achieve that by writing a custom function to select the window to display the helm buffer. And set `helm-split-window-preferred-function` to this function. I am providing one such function below

```el
;; So that helm does not use current window to display the helm window
(setq helm-split-window-in-side-p nil)


(defun my-helm-split-window (window)
  (if (one-window-p t)
      ;; With just window helm does the right thing
      (split-window
       (selected-window) nil (if (eq helm-split-window-default-side 'other)
                                 'below helm-split-window-default-side))

    ;; If there are multiple windows, select the bottom-left window
    (while (window-in-direction 'left)
      (select-window (window-in-direction 'left)))
    (while (window-in-direction 'below)
      (select-window (window-in-direction 'below)))

    (selected-window)))

(setq helm-split-window-preferred-function #'my-helm-split-window)
```

**2)** Another solution is to echo the input to helm, in the header line

This way the input can be seen at the top of the `helm` window irrespective of the position of the window

To achieve this set `helm-echo-input-in-header-line` to `t`. Additionally you can use some tips mentioned in [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/3asbyn/new_and_very_useful_helm_feature_enter_search/) reddit thread to show input only in the header